# Conditional probability of two random variables given a joint PMF table

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

Consider two random variables  and  as seen in the following joint PMF table:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  &Y=2& Y=3& Y=4  \\ \hline
X=1 &1/12& 1/24& 1/24 \\ \hline
X=2 &1/6& 1/12& 1/8  \\ \hline
X=3 &1/4& 1/8&    1/12 \\ \hline
\end{array}

I calculate the conditional probability of $P_{|}(1|2)$ as follows:

$$P(X=1|Y=2) = \dfrac{P((X=1) \cap (Y=2))}{P(Y=2)} = \dfrac{P(X=1,Y=2)}{P(Y=2)} = \dfrac{P_{X,Y}(1,2)}{P_{Y}(2)} = \dfrac{1/12}{1/2} = \dfrac{1}{6}$$

The way this conditional probability is phrased confuses to me:

$$P_{|}(1)$$, where $$=\{{>3}\}$$

Given , then only $ = 4$ satisfies the condition. To evaluate $P_{|}(1)$:

$$P(X=1|Y=4) = \dfrac{P((X=1) \cap (Y=4))}{P(Y=4)} = \dfrac{P(X=1,Y=4)}{P(Y=4)} = \dfrac{P_{X,Y}(1,4)}{P_{Y}(4)} = \dfrac{1/24}{1/4} = \dfrac{1}{6}$$

This seems about right or am I missing something?

I am unsure as to why $P_{|}(1)$ only contains one integer and excludes the vertical condition line.

So to solve $P_{|}(2)$ given the same condition for $=\{{>3}\}$, then $(=2|=4)$?

Any feedback is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Both your calculations seem correct.  Indeed the event $X=1$ seems to be independent of the value of $Y$ or any function of $Y$

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was actually questioning $P_{|}(1)$. So to solve $P_{|}(2)$ given the same condition for $=\{{>3}\}$, then $(=2|=4)$ is the way to go? @Henry

Comment: Seems reasonable to me

Comment: I posted another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398447/conditional-variance-of-discrete-random-variables) on conditional probability. Maybe you can shed some light on it @Henry