# Conditional variance of discrete random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-probability, variance

Given  and  are independent discrete random variables with

$$\mathbb{E}[]=0, \mathbb{E}[]=1, \mathbb{E}[^2]=8, \mathbb{E}[^2]=10$$

and

$$Var()=Var()=8$$

Let $=$ and $=+$.

To find $\mathbb{E}[AB]$, then

$$\mathbb{E}[AB]=\mathbb{E}[XY(X+Y)]=\mathbb{E}[X^2Y + XY^2]=\mathbb{E}[X^2Y] + \mathbb{E}[XY^2]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y]+\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=8$$

But I get a different value using the following approach

$$\mathbb{E}[AB]=\mathbb{E}[A]\mathbb{E}[B]=\mathbb{E}[XY]\mathbb{E}[X+Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]*(\mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y])=0$$

Out of curiosity, why is this the case?

I want to believe that my first approach is correct, thus $\mathbb{E}[AB]=8$.

Anyways, I will proceed with my actual question.

To find $(A)$, given $()=[()^2]−([])^2$, then

$$\mathsf{Var}(A)=\mathbb{E}[(XY)^2]-(\mathbb{E}[XY])^2=\mathbb{E}[X^2Y^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y])^2=\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=8*10=80$$

So far so good, however, I am having troubles finding the conditional probability for $(|Y=1)$.

I know that the conditional variance of a random variable is determined with

$$\mathsf{Var}(X|Y)=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X|Y])^2|Y]$$

By substituting in the respective parameters, then

$$\mathsf{Var}(XY|Y=1)=\mathbb{E}[(XY-\mathbb{E}[XY|Y=1])^2|Y=1]$$

And now what? There is a bunch of nested conditional expectations.

Good thing is, there is a formula for conditional expectations:

$$µ_{X | Y =y} = \mathbb{E}(X | Y = y) = \sum xf_{X | Y} (x | y).$$

Sad thing is, I don't know what to do with it. Am I overcomplicating things?

What I do know is that $\mathbb{E}(X | Y = y)$ is the mean value of $X$, when $Y$ is fixed at $y$. I already found out the value for $(A)$ which I don't know if it's useful to find the conditional one or not. Also, $\mathbb{E}[XY]=0$.

- From here onwards, how do I calculate the conditional variance?
- And is there an easier perhaps more straightforward way to evaluate it?

Hopefully someone can help me figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: If $\mathbb{E}[]=1, \mathbb{E}[Y^2]=10$ then $Var()=9$.  Alternatively, if $\mathbb{E}[]=1, Var()=8$ then $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=9$.

Comment: $\Bbb E(AB) \neq \Bbb E(A)~\Bbb E(B)$ because $XY$ is *not uncorrelated* with $X+Y$.

Comment: Given that $()≠() ()$ then $A$ and $B$ are not independent. Correct me if I'm wrong @GrahamKemp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation $$\mathsf{Var}(A)=\mathbb{E}[XY]^2-(\mathbb{E}[XY])^2=\mathbb{E}[X^2Y^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y])^2=\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=8*10=80$$
contains typographical errors.  The corrected equation, with corrections in red, should look like this:
$$\mathsf{Var}(A)=\mathbb{E}[\color{red}{(}XY\color{red}{)^2}]-(\mathbb{E}[XY])^2=\mathbb{E}[X^2Y^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y])^2=\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=8*10=80.$$

The reason is akin to the reason why $f(x)^2$ is taken to mean $(f(x))^2$, rather than $f(x^2)$.

The conditional variance $$\mathsf{Var}(A \mid Y = 1)$$ is straightforward:  Given that $Y = 1$, then $A = XY = X$, so $$\mathsf{Var}(A \mid Y = 1) = \mathsf{Var}(X \mid Y = 1) = \mathsf{Var}(X),$$ where the last equality that states that the conditional variance of $X$ given $Y = 1$ is equal to the unconditional variance of $X$, holds because $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Those typographical errors will be the end of me. I still have to get used to Tex plus it was a long night yesterday so my apologies for that; I just corrected the equation in my question. Nonetheless, your explanation is exactly what I was looking for, so many thanks to you @heropup

Comment: Seeing that $XY$ simply become $X$ in this case scenario, then $\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}[(X)^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^2=8$. Another example to check if I understand this properly. To determine $\mathsf{Var}(A|X=2)$ given that $=2$, then $==Y$ thus $(∣=2)=(∣=2)=()=10$. Or did I miss something here? I really want to get the hang of this, so please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @nimen55290 No; given $X = 2$, then $A = XY = 2Y$, hence $$\mathsf{Var}(A \mid X = 2) = \mathsf{Var}(2Y \mid X = 2) = \mathsf{Var}(2Y) = 4 \mathsf{Var}(Y).$$

Comment: I think I get it now. Simply substitute in the value of conditioning on either $X = x$ or $Y = y$, depending on the case scenario. The transition from $(2)=4()$ is done by squaring the constant and factorising it out of the $()$ function, e.g. $(2)=2^2()$ and $(3)=3^2()$ and so on? Anyways, your really answered my question and explained it very well so I'm going to mark this as an answer. Thanks again @heropup

Answer (score 2):

When $A$ and $B$ are not independent, $E[AB]\overset{?}{=}E[A]E[B]$ does not necessarily hold.

---

You wrote down the definition of conditional variance incorrectly.

The expression $E[(Y - E[Y \mid X])^2 \mid X]$ is the definition of $\text{Var}(Y \mid X)$, not $\text{Var}(X \mid Y)$.

So, $\text{Var}(XY \mid Y=1) = E[(XY - E[XY \mid Y=1])^2 \mid Y=1]$. If you do the computation you'll end up with $\text{Var}(X)$ which makes sense: since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $XY$ simply becomes $X$ when conditioning on $Y=1$.

Comment: Oops, my bad! Thanks for pointing that out @angryavian . I updated the formula for conditional variance in my question.

Comment: So now I am left with $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X|1])^2|1]$, but how do I simplify the nested conditions to be left only with the bare expectations of $X$, as in terms of $E[X]$ or $E[X^2]$? @angryavian