# Independence and conditional independence of discrete random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, independence, variance

This question is actually based on a previous question that I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398447/conditional-variance-of-discrete-random-variables), with some minor edits:

Given  and  are independent discrete random variables with

$$\mathbb{E}[]=0, \mathbb{E}[]=1, \mathbb{E}[()^2]=8, \mathbb{E}[()^2]=9, \mathbb{E}[Z]=1, \mathbb{E}[(Z)^2]=9$$

and

$$Var()=Var()=Var(Z)=8$$

Let $=$ and $=Z(+)$.

$A$ and $B$ are independent if the distribution of X is not influenced by the values taken by Y, and vice versa.

So if I understand this correctly, the mean of the values changes when substituting in different values for $X=x$ and $Y=y$ respectively, then they're dependent, else they're independent. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Same goes for conditional probability distribution of $X$ and $Y$ given ${\displaystyle Z}$, like seen in the defenition below.

Conditional independence of random variables according to wikipedia:

> That is, ${\displaystyle X}$ and ${\displaystyle Y}$ are conditionally
> independent given ${\displaystyle Z}$ if and only if, given any value
> of ${\displaystyle Z}$, the probability distribution of
> ${\displaystyle X}$ is the same for all values of ${\displaystyle Y}$
> and the probability distribution of ${\displaystyle Y}$ is the same
> for all values of ${\displaystyle X}$

My question is

Is there a way to tell if $A$ and $B$ are independent by calculating the expectation of $\mathbb{E}[A]$ and $\mathbb{E}[B]$, and also the variance of $Var(A)$ and $Var(B)$ and using those values to determine their independence? If so, how?

The same question applies for conditional independence e.g. using the expecation and variance to determine if  and  are conditionally independent, by conditioning on either $=\{{0,1,2,...}\}$ or $Y=\{{0,1,2,...}\}$.

After all, like calculated in my other question:

$$(∣=1)=(∣=1)=()=(∣X=1)=(Y∣X=1)=(Y)$$

Since $$Var()=Var()=Var(Z)=8$$

I am really struggling with the topic of independence so I beg you to please bare with me on this one. Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

Cheers to @angryavian for denoting the following

> When $A$ and $B$ are not independent, $E[AB]\overset{?}{=}E[A]E[B]$ does not necessarily hold.

Proving that $A$ and $B$ are not independent with

$$[AB]≠[A][B]$$
$$[XY*Z(X+Y)]≠[XY]*[Z(X+Y)]$$

Substituting in the values for both sides yields $8≠0$, thus $A$ and $B$ are dependent.

The only thing I still don't get is the conditional independence.

How can I tell if $$ and $$ are conditionally independent, given =0 or =1?

I thought about substituting in the values e.g. =1 then $A=Y$ and $B=Z(1+Y)$

Comment: It would help to narrow your post to a precise focused question. I don't understand the relevance of your example and particularly what $Z$ is. You mention wiki; did you read their mathematical definition of independence (not just the English statement)?

Comment: Yes, I did @Golden_Ratio but I'm having a hard time understanding it. It says to use the cumulative distribution function (CDF) but I have never used it before. That's why I was wondering if there's a way to determine independency and conditional independency using only expectation and variance but until now I've found no method. An example to guide me would really be helpful.

Comment: You should first learn about the CDF and other basic probability theory before understanding independence of random variables. Independence has a precise mathematical definition. One equivalent definition of independence is that $X,Y$ are independent if and only if for all measurable functions $f,g$ we have $E[f(X)g(Y)]=E[f(X)]E[g(Y)].$ This is not very useful to check independence though since you would have to consider infinitely many functions.

Comment: Yes, I will definitely read more about CDFs. However, I find your comment about measurable functions very interesting. So $[()()]=[()][()]$ means that both $X$ and $Y$ are independent? In my case scenario this would be $[()((+))]=[()][((+))]$ and now I would have to iterate through all $x$, $y$, $z$

Comment: Well as far as your example, there is no reason that $XY$  and $Z(X+Y)$ should be independent (after all they both have $X,Y$ in them), but you technically need more info to determine this. For instance, if $Z=0$, then they are trivially independent (any random variable is independent of a constant). As far as my last comment, while it may be interesting, I don't see how it's really useful; you have to check the equality holds for **all** (measurable) functions $f,g$.

Comment: And I am not sure why you mention "iterate through all $x,y,z$"...what iteration? Perhaps you were thinking of the summation across all $x,y,z$ using the definition of expected value for discrete random variables?

Comment: Here's a starter course: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/

Comment: Yes, summation is what I meant @Golden_Ratio

Comment: It makes sense that both $A$ and $B$ depend on $X$ and $Y$. Applying that on both the conditional independence of $XY$ and $Z(X+Y)$,  given that $X=1$ leads to $Y$ and $Z(1+Y)$ respectively, then both $A$ and $B$ are not independent because the value of $Y$ in $B$ is affected by $X$ in this case $X=1$ and so on for every $X={0,1,2,...}$? And what happens when $X=0$? Then $A=0$ an empty set that is a linearly independent, but conditionally? I hope to get this soon because I'm not blessed with independence @Golden_Ratio

Comment: You will be blessed with knowledge of independence and much more if you start from the basics. It looks you are jumping from step 1 to step 100 here. Take a look at that link I shared. It's not productive to talk about conditional independence when you still need to learn regular independence!

Comment: You can also check out edX, khan academy, coursera for other probability courses

Comment: I updated my question @Golden_Ratio feel free to share your thoughts. If you would really like to help me out, post how to determine   and  are conditionally independent, given =0 or =1 and I'll gladly mark it as an answer. After all, I didn't find any similar question on math stack exchange.